# Identify a free interpretation of the Babylonian confusion

Tags: identification-request

Once I've read a story that the real reason for the Babylonian confusion was not divine at all but a striking translator guild (I am not sure whether they were slaves or just had worse payment).

Lovely, isn't it?

Who has (originally) written it and under which title?